# Query for a node, filtering using uid of child nodes (relations)

Tags: dgraph

If have a schema "Like" that has relations to User Schema (user_id) and Post Schema (object_id). How can I query for the "Like" nodes that have `user_id = (some_uid)` and `object_id = (some_uid)`.

I am using [dgraph-io/dgraph-js](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph-js).

```
User Schema               Post Schema             Like Schema

uid                       uid                     uid
first_name                type                    object_id (maps post)
last_name                 content                 user_id (maps user)
email                     title
created_at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  likes(func: has(like.object_id)) @filter(uid_in(like.object_id, 0x2) and uid_in(like.user_id, 0x3)){
    like.object_id {
      uid
      post.type
      post.content
      post.title
    }
    like.user_id{
      uid
      user.email
      user.first_name
      user.last_name
    }
  }
}
```